# Matrix Multiplication By Rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Lets y be a row vector $(y_1 y_2... y_n)$ 

and A to be $nxm$ matrix  \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... &a_{1m} \\
a_{21} & a_{11} & ... &a_{2m} \\
... & ... & ... &... \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... &a_{nm} \end{array}

prove that yA=$\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_i*R_i(A)$

but multiplication is defined row-column so every $y_1$ is multiply by $a_{11}  a_{12}  ... a_{1m}$ but they do not sum up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_1$ is multiplied by $(a_{11}\ a_{12}\ ...\ a_{1m})$ yielding the row vector $(y_1a_{11}\quad y_1a_{12}\quad  ...\quad  y_1a_{1m})$.

Similarly $y_2$ is multiplied by the second row vector $(a_{21}\ a_{22}\ ...\ a_{2m})$ yielding the row vector $(y_2a_{21}\quad y_2a_{22}\quad ...\quad y_2a_{2m})$.

When we sum up these row vectors, entry by entry, we get the row vector $yA$.

Comment: isn't yA a column vector?

Comment: Nope. $yA$ is a row vector. The result of matrix multiplication has the number of rows of the left hand argument, and the number of columns of the right hand argument.